# I got an FaultException with "an item with the same key already exists"

Tags: c#, wcf

I get a System.ServiceModel.FaultException if i call a method from my webservice.
I call two methods of a service, here is the interface from both:

```
[OperationContract(IsOneWay = false, IsInitiating = true, IsTerminating = true)]
SaveResult CreateApprovalRequest(Guid requestId, Request request);
[OperationContract(IsOneWay = false, IsInitiating = true, IsTerminating = true)]
RequestSource GetRequestSource(Guid requestId, string source)

[OperationContract(IsOneWay = false, IsInitiating = true, IsTerminating = true)]
SaveResult CreateApprovalRequest(Guid requestId, Request request);

[OperationContract(IsOneWay = false, IsInitiating = true, IsTerminating = true)]
RequestSource GetRequestSource(Guid requestId, string source);
```

The first method call is successfully but the second not.
Both methods could use the same connected client object but every method should be run alone. So I flag both as `Initiating and Terminating.`

What is the problem here?

Comment: Probably something in the server side code, but without that code it is just a guess

Comment: The server code just works, i tested it in a test application without the service reference. Actually i do not understand what the error tries to say to me.

Comment: The errors says that somewhere a keyed collection receives an element whose key is already present in the collection (like if you add two items with the same key to a Dictionary) If you debug your code and you receive this error when executing the server side call then.... (And testing with a different application is not a conclusive proof of correctness because you should use the same data of your main app))

Comment: The problem is, that i did not use any dictionaries in the second method.

Answer (score 0):

If you are adding to a dictionary somewhere, that's 99% chance of where the error is occurring, whether that makes sense or not.

You can shed some light into what's going on by turning on tracing, replicating your error, and checking the log. Tracing gives very detailed step by step information about what happened.

You add this to the web.config on the server, right under the root config element. You can use whatever path and file name you want, of course.

```xml
<configuration>
    <system.diagnostics>
        <trace autoflush="true" />
        <sources>
            <source name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="All" propagateActivity="true">
                <listeners>
                    <add name="traceListener" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener" initializeData="D:\IISLogs\WCFLog\MyServerTrace.svclog" />
                </listeners>
            </source>
        </sources>
    </system.diagnostics>
</configuration>
```

You can view the log in notepad or Visual Studio, but the [Service Trace Viewer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732023(v=vs.110).aspx) is perhaps easier.

To get it, You need to download [Microsoft SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8279) (your version of this may need to vary). The program will be at the following path after you installed SDK:

> C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\bin\SvcTraceViewer.exe

You must debug on the WCF server. There's a rule in debugging "Don't think. Look". Don't assume anything but the debugger will help you actually look at it.

If you are not debugging, the dll you think goes along with the current code may not go along with it. You can use [Telerik Just Decompile](http://www.telerik.com/products/decompiler.aspx) to verify the code in the compiled dll is really the same as what you think it is.

Comment: Ok, i will try this and hope i can find the error. Thx.

Comment: Nothing found. The problem is, the i got the exception on running this small method:

 public SaveResult CreateNewApprovalRequest(Guid requestId, Request request)
 {
  return null;
 }